# Call API with OAUTH2 Authorization using com.sun.jersey Java dependency

Tags: java, rest, oauth-2.0, jersey

Currently i'm having trouble to call an API with OAUTH2 that give access token using sun jersey library.

this is the API example details:

POST /api/oauth/token HTTP/1.1
curl https://api.xxxx.com/api/oauth/token
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
-H "Authorization: Basic 1234567890qwertyQWERTY"
-d "grant_type=client_credentials"

I have no experience to call an API with AUTH2 authorization. is there any code example to call an API with OAUTH2 authorization using sun jersey API assuming that i just need to parse these parameters to call API with OAUTH2 Authorization? i tried to search an example but have no results. And should I include com.sun.jersey.oauth dependency or i can just use com.sun.jersey.api.client to call the API?

Comment: what kind of trouble? can you share your code?

Comment: sorry for late post.. i hav solve this by only use com.sun.jersey.api.client to call the API